# In SSIS, How to fix this exceptions (Rebex.Net.SmtpException, Rebex.Net.ProxySocketException & System.Net.Sockets.SocketException)

Tags: c#, ssis, smtp, smtp-auth, rebex

SSIS package in which i am using Send Mail Task Plus to send email via (email-smtp.us-east-1.amazonaws.com). 
My package is running fine on testing server but when i try to execute it on dev server it shows exception. 
I also tried to "telnet email-smtp.us-east-1.amazonaws.com 587" on CMD but not connecting via telnet on dev server. 
It seems like "email-smtp.us-east-1.amazonaws.com" not accessible from my dev server. Port i am using is 587 and same port is working fine on my testing server.
Please suggest what can i do to fix it.

Stack Trace:

2019-08-27 08:24:09.315 Opening log file.

2019-08-27 08:24:09.315 INFO FileLogWriter(1)[10] Info: Assembly: Rebex.Common 2017 R6.3 for .NET 2.0-3.5

2019-08-27 08:24:09.315 INFO FileLogWriter(1)[10] Info: Platform: Windows 6.2.9200 64-bit; CLR: 4.0.30319.42000

2019-08-27 08:24:09.315 DEBUG FileLogWriter(1)[10] Info: Culture: en; Windows-1252

2019-08-27 08:24:09.315 DEBUG Smtp(1)[10] Info: State changed from 'Disconnected' to 'Connecting'.

2019-08-27 08:24:09.315 INFO Smtp(1)[10] Info: Connecting to email-smtp.us-east-1.amazonaws.com:587 using Smtp.

2019-08-27 08:24:09.315 INFO Smtp(1)[10] Info: Assembly: Rebex.Smtp 2017 R6.3 for .NET 2.0-3.5

2019-08-27 08:24:09.316 INFO Smtp(1)[10] Info: Platform: Windows 6.2.9200 64-bit; CLR: 4.0.30319.42000

2019-08-27 08:24:09.316 DEBUG Smtp(1)[10] Info: Culture: en; Windows-1252

2019-08-27 08:24:09.316 DEBUG ProxySocket(1)[10] Proxy: Resolving 'email-smtp.us-east-1.amazonaws.com'.

2019-08-27 08:24:09.319 DEBUG ProxySocket(1)[10] Proxy: Connecting to none proxy at 3.92.111.20:587.

2019-08-27 08:24:30.323 DEBUG Smtp(1)[10] Info: State changed from 'Connecting' to 'Disconnected'.

2019-08-27 08:24:30.429 ERROR Smtp(1)[10] Info: Rebex.Net.SmtpException: A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not properly respond after a period of time, or established connection failed because connected host has failed to respond. ---> Rebex.Net.ProxySocketException: A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not properly respond after a period of time, or established connection failed because connected host has failed to respond. ---> System.Net.Sockets.SocketException: A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not properly respond after a period of time, or established connection failed because connected host has failed to respond 3.92.111.20:587
   at System.Net.Sockets.Socket.DoConnect(EndPoint endPointSnapshot, SocketAddress socketAddress)

at System.Net.Sockets.Socket.Connect(EndPoint remoteEP)

at Rebex.Net.CRV.EI(EndPoint I)

at Rebex.Net.ProxySocket.Connect(EndPoint remoteEP)

--- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at Rebex.Net.ProxySocket.Connect(EndPoint remoteEP)

at Rebex.Net.HTP..ctor(Smtp I, ISocketFactory J, String C, Int32 D)

at Rebex.Net.Smtp.RZ(String I, Int32 J, TlsParameters C, SslMode D)

--- End of inner exception stack trace ---

at Rebex.Net.Smtp.RZ(String I, Int32 J, TlsParameters C, SslMode D)

2019-08-27 08:24:30.429 DEBUG Smtp(1)[10] Info: State changed from 'Disconnected' to 'Disposed'.

Comment: You can check whether there is a fire wall blocking your connection in your dev server.

Comment: If even telnet connection does not work, it seems there is not a problem in the Rebex SMTP component. If you still suspect the problem is in the Rebex SMTP component, please post full stack-trace from your exception here.

Comment: Check the stack trace now

Comment: @Subbu can you please elaborate your answer like how to do check ??

Comment: Please answer its urgent

Answer (score 0):

Expanding the comment as an Answer to include screen shots:

In Windows Server 2016, the application is called `Windows Firewall with Advanced Security` (available in the start menu). Other Windows version would have a similar app.

[image]

When you launch it, you would get a screen similar to the below:

[image]

If you have "Firewall is on" message, get in touch with the System Administrator responsible for this server and provide all these details.

The firewall can be configured to allow your mail connections.

Additionally, some of the anti-virus products (e.g., McAfee) can be configured to block access to send mails. In this scenario, your anti-virus log would have some details if it is blocking your connection. In this case, also go to your System Administrator to configure it to allow mails from your application.